# FileInputStream using package path

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to read a file like :

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("/com/test/Test.xml");
```

I am always getting the file not found exception. How can i make it work? Will the inputstream takes the relative path or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this can take relative path.

Why your expression does not work? Very simple: your path `/com/test/Test.xml` is absolute because it starts with `/`, so you are actually looking for file located in `/com/test/` directory starting from root.

How to solve the problem?

I believe that you are trying to find file located under your project. So, you can use relative path like `./com/test/Test.xml` or `com/test/Test.xml`. This will probably help. Probably because I do not know what is your current working directory and your file structure. Your current directory is where you are located when running `java`. If you are running from IDE typically the working directory is your project directory.

In this case I believe that path `./com/test/Test.xml` is invalid because file `Test.xml` is not located directly under project root but somewhere under `./src/resources/com/test` or so.

In this case probably you do not want to read the file as a file but as a resource (located into your classpath). In this case use

`getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/test/Test.xml")`

Answer (score 4):

Try using

[class.getResourceAsStream(path)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String). In that case, path will have to be relative to the folder containing the class invoking this statement.

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/test/Test.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
String str = "Test.xml";
  File file = new File(str);
  String absolutePathOfFirstFile = file.getAbsolutePath();
  FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(absolutePathOfFirstFile);
```

Comment: the above answer is really good explanation. please read that

Answer (score 0):

Your path must be incorrect. You can check the current directory by using `System.getProperty("user.dir");` or printing the path of `new File(".")`